# IVBricker problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

This is the first game I do, but I have a problem with the bricks. I posted a video on youtube. Please help me. Thanks.....http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP8iLs_g0MQ

Comment: What have you tried? What source code do you use? What, specifically, is the problem? A link to a YouTube video is not sufficient. Please give this a read and take better care to clarify your questions: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

you want to create a grid of bricks???? use this it may helps

int outer = 32/4;
    int inner=4;
    outer=(32/4 -outer)>0? outer :outer+1;
    NSLog(@"outer is as following %d",outer);
    for (int i=0,k=0,t=0;i

```
    if (i == outer-1) {
        inner=32%4;
                }
    for (int j=0; j<inner; j++) {

        boximage = [[uiimageview alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebox.png"]];
        boximage.frame = CGRectMake(i*40,j*40,40,40);
        boximage.tag = t;
        [self.view addSubview:boximage];

        NSLog(@"tag images  %d",boximage.tag);
                //[boximage release];

        k++;
        t++;
    }

        }
```